# How to use pivot in SQL (not as DataFrame grouping operator)?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe and I was trying to convert this dataframe operation in to sql use `pivot` function

```
  val df = Seq(
    (1, "a,b,c"),
    (2, "b,c")
  ).toDF("id", "page_path")
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

  df.show()
  df
    .withColumn("splitted", split($"page_path", ","))
    .withColumn("exploded", explode($"splitted"))
    .groupBy("id")
    .pivot("exploded")
    .count().show
```

output produced :

```
+---+----+---+---+
| id|   a|  b|  c|
+---+----+---+---+
|  1|   1|  1|  1|
|  2|null|  1|  1|
+---+----+---+---+
```

I saw this [databricks link](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html) to use `pivot` function in sql way, I tried to applied and failed..

Anyone has any idea of applying pivot function in a sql way ?

I just tried this way,

```
  spark.sql(
    """
      (select * from (Select id, exploded from ( select id, explode(split( page_path ,',')) as exploded from df )
      group by id, exploded )
      Pivot
      (id, exploded)   )
             """.stripMargin
  ).show
```

is producing the result like

```
+---+--------+
| id|exploded|
+---+--------+
|  2|       c|
|  1|       c|
|  1|       b|
|  2|       b|
|  1|       a|
+---+--------+
```

not like the above output showed using dataframe operations

I tried this also

```
 spark.sql(
    """
      select * from  (  select * from df lateral view explode(split( page_path ,',')) as exploded )
          pivot (exploded)
             """.stripMargin
  ).show
```

Exception :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Number of column aliases does not match number of columns. Number of
>   column aliases: 1; number of columns: 3.; line 2 pos 21

breaking my head, was thinking whether is possible or not.

Comment: You sure you not make a simple mistake?     ```.pivot("exploded")``` vs ```Pivot (id, exploded)```

Comment: `.pivot("exploded")`  is intended I was getting an error (`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Number of column aliases does not match number of columns. Number of column aliases: 1; number of columns: 2.; line 2 pos 21`) while doing with above query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We `don't` have to mention **groupBy** clause using sql pivot as Spark implicitly performs groupBy.

[**`From documentation:`**](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html)

> An important idea about pivot is that it performs a grouped 
>   aggregation based on a list of implicit **group-by** columns together with 
>   the **pivot column**. The implicit group-by columns are columns from the 
>   FROM clause that do not appear in any aggregate function or as the 
>   pivot column.

In **`pivot`** we need to add aggregate query on the pivoted column and in **`for`** mention the required columns list that needed in final dataset.

**`Using Spark-sql Pivot from spark-2.4:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.functions._

val df1: DataFrame = Seq((1, "a,b,c"),(2, "b,c")).toDF("id", "page_path")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
spark.sql(
    """
      |Select * from
      |( select id, explode(split( page_path ,',')) as exploded from df )
      |pivot(count(exploded) for exploded in ('a','b','c')
      |)
   """.stripMargin)
.show
```

Result :

```
+---+----+---+---+
| id|   a|  b|  c|
+---+----+---+---+
|  1|   1|  1|  1|
|  2|null|  1|  1|
+---+----+---+---+
```

**`Using Dataframe api:`**

```
df1.withColumn("splitted", split($"page_path", ",")).
withColumn("exploded", explode($"splitted")).
groupBy("id").
pivot("exploded").
count().
show
```

Result :

```
+---+----+---+---+
| id|   a|  b|  c|
+---+----+---+---+
|  1|   1|  1|  1|
|  2|null|  1|  1|
+---+----+---+---+
```